# Escaping HTML special character with JSP or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

My JSP file contains a table with the following row:

```
<td class="description" id="${doc.id}"></td>
```

I want it to be empty at first, as above. Later, after the page is loaded and some logic is processed, I want to fill it asynchronously with a content using JQuery `.html` method:

```
$("#${doc.id}").html("${doc.description}");
```

For regular user inputs everything works fine, but error occurs, when a user enters special character: `"`

How can I prevent application from reading that character as special, and have the application running correctly?

I have tried to use JSP escape functions like this:

```
$("#${doc.id}").html("${fn:escapeXml(doc.description)}");
```

And this:

```
$("#${doc.id}").html("<c:out value="${doc.description}"/>");
```

And neither first nor second worked. Why?

Comment: You could JSONencode it on the server

Comment: `$("#${doc.id}").html("<c:out value="${doc.description}"/>");` does not make any sense. If you already know the data, put it inside a hidden div and show/hide/copy the div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way  - seeing you already have the data on the page

```
<td class="description hide" id="${doc.id}"><c:out value="${doc.description}"/></td>
```

where

.hide is {display:none}

and then

```
$("#${doc.id}").show();
```

Comment: It looks like that's what I need. Thanks!

Comment: After giving it some thought, I realized, that it is not what I was looking for. The reason is safety - if the hiding method is at the client side, everybody can go to inspector in the browser and delete that {display:none} attribute.

Comment: And why would that suddenly be an issue - you eventually show the data in the page? If you successfully add it to a JS var, they can just view-source and read the description in the JavaScript instead of on the page

Comment: For user with some privileges I do want to show it, but for all others - I don't.

As I understand - if the results are only in the JSP file, and I don't call it at the back end, it is impossible to view it?

Comment: If not sent to the client then it is not visible on the client. That is correct